# How to define a constant in the swagger definition of a NestJS Class?

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-swagger

I have a bunch of Exceptions that use the same interface, so it is easier for the frontend to distinct between them from the same endpoint.

I want to be able to document in swagger that `MyWeirdExpection` has a property `type` that has the value `my-weird-exception` (it comes from an string ENUM if that is relevant).

Is this possible to do?

Something like:

```js
enum MyEnum {
   MyWeirdExpection: 'my-weird-exception',
   RegularExpection: 'my-regular-expection'
... more
}



  @ApiProperty({
    description: 'Frontend can react on this property',
    type: String, // <-----------WHAT HERE?
  })
  type: MyEnum.MyWeirdExpection;
```

Again, my goal is that in the swagger definition, says that `MyWeirdExpection.type` is the constant `'my-weird-exception'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will provide a type of `MyEnum.MyWeirdExpection` with the value populated as 'my-weird-exception':

```js
@ApiProperty({
    description: "Search by asset type",
    required: false,
    default: MyEnum.MyWeirdExpection,
    type: MyEnum.MyWeirdExpection
})
type: string | undefined;
```

Comment: 'assetType4' should be 'type'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).